# php exec script from different folder

Tags: php, bash, shell

I want to run `~/bin/git_cache_meta.sh` in a folder `~/www/project/folderA/` with a php script.

My script is located in the `www` folder and looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    chdir('project/folderA/');
    exec('git_cache_meta.sh --apply');
```

The script shows the error `sh: 1: git_cache_meta.sh: not found` how can I tell exec that the script `git_cache_meta.sh` is in the folder `~/bin/git_cache_meta.sh` ? I do not want to copy the file `git_cache_meta.sh` to `~/www/project/folderA/`.

Comment: Does you `www` account have access to this other folder? Possibly more importantly ___should it have access___ or would that be a security risk

Comment: @RiggyFolly Its all on my local laptop, there is no security risk here.

Comment: So you dont mind you laptop gettin hacked? Or are you one of these people that believes that *nix is unhackable

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I have no idea how someone could hack my laptop in this scenario. I have two folders one called `www` and one called `bin` they are both on my laptop in the folder `/home/myusername/`. I want to exectue a script from one folder in the other folder. Why is this is risk?

Comment: You have a web server running. Therefore you have a well understood attack vector on your machine

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using XAMPP on my laptop. Its not a online webserver. I use it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use full path of the file and be sure it has the necessary access.

i.e.

in your case:

```
~/bin/git_cache_meta.sh
```

Also, use chmod +x to give it the permission to be executable.

Comment: oh I see.. Is there nothing like a $PATH variable for my PHP script where I can just map all commands to their corresponding folders? Do I really have to always enter the full path of the script?